# Isomorphism between group and product group

Tags: abstract-algebra

I got stuck with an exercise and need a hint...

Prove that $(\mathbb{Z}/15\mathbb{Z})^*$ is isomorpic to $\mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, and conclude that $(\mathbb{Z}/15\mathbb{Z})^*$ is not cyclic

From previous exercises I proved that:

$(\mathbb{Z}/15\mathbb{Z})$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}) \times (\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})$

I have calculated the size of the two groups and tried to go from there but with no luck at all, please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if two rings are isomorphic then so are their unit groups. Moreover, $$(R\times S)^* \cong R^*\times S^*.$$
The theorem on primitive roots implies that $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^*$ is cyclic. Can you go from here?

Comment: Does this also apply in group theory?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If $R$ is a ring, then $R$ is a group under addition and $R^*$ is a group under multiplication. Also, an isomorphism of rings restricts to an isomorphism of the two abovementioned underlying groups. In your previous exercise, did you prove that $\mathbb{Z}/15\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})\times(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})$ as rings, or just as groups?

Answer (score 1):

Have you calculated the Cayley table for $(\Bbb Z/15\Bbb Z)^*$?  It has only 8 elements, so it won't take long to write the table.  While you're writing the table, you might notice the correspondence to $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$.  If you don't notice it right away, you can still use the Cayley table to find elements of orders 2 and 4 and see if those are the two generators you are looking for.

(You do know that $(\Bbb Z/15\Bbb Z)^*$ has not 15 but 8 elements, right?  That star is important!)

Answer (score 0):

You need to show that $(\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z)^*$ and $(\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z)^*$ are cyclic.  Since $|(\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z)^*|=2$, that's clear.  For the other factor, find an element of $(\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z)^*$ of order 4.